# CodeIgniter active record limit with join

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have the following function in my model:

```
function getLocations($limit = null, $offset = null){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('location');
    $this->db->join('process', 'process.process_id=location.process_id');
    $this->db->join('line', 'line.line_id=process.line_id');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('location_id', 'asc');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

It is then executed using: `$this->the_model->getLocations()` resulting in the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "location"
JOIN "process" ON "process"."process_id"="location"."process_id"
JOIN "line" ON "line"."line_id"="process"."line_id"
ORDER BY "location_id" asc LIMIT 0
```

Notice `LIMIT 0`, this does not happen when I execute `$this->db->order_by('item_id', 'asc')->get('item', $limit, $offset)->result()`. There is no `LIMIT 0` even limit and offset is `null`. So, how to solve this? I already add `if` condition when limit is null.

Comment: hi, null does not mean being = 0, you can try doing function getLocations($limit = 0,$offset = 0)

Answer (score 1):

`0` is a value. This does not mean `0` is `NULL`. While `NULL` has no value at all.

For your case,

```
function getLocations($limit = 1, $offset = 0){
                               ^            ^ 
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('location');
    $this->db->join('process', 'process.process_id=location.process_id');
    $this->db->join('line', 'line.line_id=process.line_id');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $this->db->order_by('location_id', 'asc');
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Put the `limit` at least `1` and offset to be `0` for default values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function getLocations($limit , $offset){
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT *
        FROM location
        JOIN process ON process.process_id=location.process_id
        JOIN line ON line.line_id=process.line_id
        ORDER BY location_id asc LIMIT $limit, $offset");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Don't set `$limit = NULL`. this will fix the issue

Comment: thanks, but sometimes I need limit and offset, sometimes not.

Comment: so then use another function. If you use function it will not make any different to your  project performance

Answer (score 0):

thanks for those who response to my question.

I solved this by adjusting the code to:

```
function getLocations($limit = null, $offset = null){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->join('process', 'process.process_id=location.process_id');
    $this->db->join('line', 'line.line_id=process.line_id');
    $this->db->order_by('location_id', 'asc');
    return $this->db->get('location', $limit, $offset)->result();
}
```

this way there is no `LIMIT 0` in generated query even `$limit` is `null`.

thanks a lot.